# finding intersection where one set needs to be derived

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two tables: `output_hash` and `baseline`. `output_hash` contains `plot_id`. `baseline` contains `plot_number`. The first 6 digits of `plot_id` are made up of the `plot_number`. How can I find the intersection between the `plot_id` in `output_hash` and `plot_number` in `baseline`? I want the result to be `plot_number` (not `baseline`). So just to be clear the value of `plot_id` contains `plot_number`.

So if `111234_5` was in `plot_id` and `111234` was in `plot_number`, I would want it in my result. But if `222345_2` was in `plot_id` but no `plot_number` started with `222345` then this shouldn't be in the result (similarly if `222345_2` was in `plot_id` but no `plot_number` started with `222345`, then `222345` would be left out of result).

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `exists` operator with a `like` operator in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM   output_hash o
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   baseline b
               WHERE  o.plot_id LIKE b.plot_number || '%')
```

Comment: This is going to return all rows in case `b.plot_number` is null because the result of the `concat()` will be `%` then. It might be better to use `||` so that the result of the concatenation will be `null` as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I forgot about the caveat wrt `concat` - thanks! Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
     *
   FROM output_hash
   JOIN baseline
     ON SUBSTR(plot_id, 1, 6) = plot_number::TEXT;